# Laravel undefined offset

Tags: laravel

I have a site who shows me offers of the users:

with a foreach I can see all offers

```
@foreach ($praktikas as $praktika)
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 pt-4 card-wrapper">
        <div class="card offer-card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img class="img-fluid" alt="Logo der Firma: {{$user[$praktika->firma -1]->avatar}}" src="{{ asset('uploads/avatars/' . $user[$praktika->firma -1]->avatar) }}">
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="text-dark">{{ $praktika->stellenname }}</h4>
                <a href="{{ route('angebot.details',['id'=>$praktika->firma]) }}">Jetzt mehr anzeigen »</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

now I have a new user with the id 88 but it calls me undefined `offset: 87` ??

I know where the problem is, it is because this:

```
$user[$praktika->firma -1]->avatar
```

it can not find a user with the id 88

if I want to show a users like this:

```
$user[83]->avatar
```

everything works but it shows me no user with the id 88 but I can see it in my database i have this user!

I dont know what to do? because it works all the time and now I don't know what happened.

this is my controller:

```
public function showpraktika()
{
    $praktikas = DB::table('angebots')
        ->where('stellentyp', 'Praktikum')
        ->orderBy('stellenname', 'asc')
        ->get();
    $row = DB::table('angebots')
        ->where('stellentyp', 'Praktikum')
        ->count();
    $user = DB::table('users')->get();
    return view('user/praktika', ['praktikas' => $praktikas, 'row' => $row, 'user' => $user]);
}
```

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: The relationship just seems wrong.  Why would the index of $users match the firma, aka company, minus 1?

Comment: if i dont do -1 it shows me the wrong firma idk why but this was my solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you write $user[88] you're not looking for the user with id = 88, you're looking for an index.

If user is a Laravel collection, use :

```
$user->firstWhere('id', $praktika->firma -1)->avatar;
```

Here you can see all methods availables for collections in Laravel, that's pretty useful : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#available-methods

Comment: oh my god thank you so much!!! you saved my life! ahhhh i thought everytime im lookign for the id and thats why everything went wrong and i dont know why puuuuh thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

To get user by id please use `User::find($your_id_here);`

Comment: That works but if user is already a collection that contains this user, you don't need to make other requests to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You access `$user[]` array by index (88) here.

```
<img class="img-fluid" alt="Logo der Firma: {{$user[$praktika->firma -1]->avatar}}"
    src="{{ asset('uploads/avatars/' . $user[$praktika->firma -1]->avatar) }}">
```

but in your `$user[]` keys are not equals to your users ids. its a zero indexed array.

so what you may do is

**Controller**

```
$users = collect();

foreach(DB::table('users')->get() as $user) {
    $users->put($user->id, $user);
}
```